# Session not working in Laravel 8.12 with Ngrok URL

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-8

Hello I know maybe some of you want to make my question as duplicate I have tried a lot to solve issue but
not getting any valid solution...

I am trying to store data in session so I will get that data on every request for login system. my demo is as below.

```
Route::get('/set', function (Request $request) {
    $request->session()->put('data', 'bla bla');
    return $request->session()->all();
});
```

OutPut:: 127.0.0.1:8000/set / https://08f91de28372.ngrok.io/set

```
{
    "_token": "VrzwNird9RTLkixKASiSoWJHpr29OchWNDQAXzCZ",
    "data": "bla bla"
}
```

now I am trying to get those session data in new request where I get nothing about stored session data
127.0.0.1:8000/get / https://08f91de28372.ngrok.io/get

```
Route::get('/get', function(Request $request){
    return $request->session()->all();
});
```

OutPut::
{
"_token": "VvR0MF4qladDK4OnycxW3X6TqCjaqqQnUL5dCv9j"
}

one thing I noticed is _token value different on each request.
Please help me I spent almost half of the day on that little things.

Comment: Hmm, this code works fine on a local project, albeit a different version (6.x instead of 8.x). Sidenote, `_token` is supposed to be different; that's the CSRF token, which changes with each request.

Comment: In `config/session.php` what is this value set to: `'lifetime'`?

Comment: @Daan 120 which is as it is when I install Laravel

Comment: [`session()->flash()`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/session#flash-data)

Comment: @TimLewis I tried with fresh Laravel and its working well. was It issue in some packages I added in issue one I used telescope and phpclassic/php-shopify

Comment: @Daan, Tim Lewis Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using ngrok URL at local and not working

Comment: Now Its working for 127.0.0.1:8000 aftrer I add lax as same_site in session.php instead of none but still not working with ngrok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was solved after adding the path in /config/session.php

```
'path' => your_ngrok_url .'/',
```

still ngrok not working when I change driver as array instead of file.

However, I don't know how 127.0.0.1:8000 is also not worked when I posted the question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Route::get('/set', function () {
    session()->put('data', 'bla bla');        
});

Route::get('/get', function(){
    return session()->get('data);
});
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of how this solves the problem and what causes it.

Comment: @BKF get blank output

Comment: blank on set or get ?

Comment: I've edited the answer, no need for Request

Comment: @BKF On get METHOD I GOT BLANK OUT PUT

Comment: I tried with fresh Laravel and its working well. was It issue in some packages I added in issue one I used telescope and phpclassic/php-shopify

Comment: @BKF Sorry I forgot to mention that I am using ngrok URL at local and not working